# Extracting URL from a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm just starting regular expression for python and came across this problem where I'm supposed to extract URLs from the string:

```
str = "<tag>http://example-1.com</tag><tag>http://example-2.com</tag>"
```

The code I have is:

```
import re

url = re.findall('<tag>(.*)</tag>', str)

print(url)
```

returns:

```
[http://example-1.com</tag><tag>http://example-2.com]
```

If anyone could point me in the direction on how I might approach this problem would it would be most appreciative!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Use `.*?` non-greedy instead of `.*` greedy one Or use `[^>]*` instead of `.*` OR best use a HTML parser

Comment: Oh wow thanks! That worked perfectly! I'll go read up on greedy and non greedy ones a bit more!

I did consider a parser but I wanted to try it in RE since it was a question under that topic.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You are using a regular expression, and matching HTML with such expressions get too complicated, too fast.

You can use BeautifulSoup to parse HTML.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

str = "<tag>http://example-1.com</tag><tag>http://example-2.com</tag>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(str, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.find_all('tag')
for tag in tags:
        print tag.text
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

I am going through an online course and wanted to keep it within the topic of RE so I decided to try it with just the RE library (which is still a mystery to me..!)

Answer (score 1):

Using only re package:

```
import re
str = "<tag>http://example-1.com</tag><tag>http://example-2.com</tag>"
url = re.findall('<tag>(.*?)</tag>', str)
print(url)
```

returns:

```
['http://example-1.com', 'http://example-2.com']
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! Thank worked! I'm now trying to figure out about greedy and non-greedy and why it would work in this instance.

Comment: Here the `.*?` is matches as few times as possible (lazy), i.e. when it finds the first closing `</tag>` it stops, whereas in the greedy `.*` as soon it finds the 2nd closing `</tag>` it matches the whole pattern.

Comment: Oh wow, your explanation made so much more sense than all the tutorials I have been reading/watching! Thanks!